# Text to gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to change the color of this text.

I did the normal process- select the text, change the fill to none from appearance then take a new fill applied the gradient.

it appears in the Appearance panel (when I select the text) that a new fill has been applied to the text but it remains still black.

I wrote the text on a circular path.[image]

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't highlight the characters. Instead, select the Type object with the Selection Tool (V), then open the Appearance panel, add a new fill, then change the fill to a gradient.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It worked!!!